# Why won't WebDriverWait work in this way? Python selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to scroll to the end of a dynamically loaded page, when you do press the end key it will load a gif to indicate that it is loading more content. I want to wait for the gif to be visible and then invisible (so it's off the page) before I press the end key again. When I use this code it won't work and times out on the invisibility wait, can anyone shed any light on this?

```
while True:
    wd.find_element_by_xpath('//body').send_keys(Keys.END)
    try:
        WebDriverWait(wd, 10, poll_frequency = 0.08).until(
            EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="films"]/div[2]/img')))
        WebDriverWait(wd, 10, poll_frequency = 0.08).until(
            EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="films"]/div[2]/img')))
    except TimeoutException:
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

In absence of any `HTML` making you code block as a baseline, I would suggest you the following changes:

1. Instead of using `send_keys(Keys.END)` use `Javascript` to scroll down as follows:

   ```
   wd.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
   ```
2. Let us not tinker with the default polling interval and leave it at default 500ms.

   ```
   WebDriverWait(wd, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="films"]/div[2]/img')))
   ```
3. Finally, while we wait for `invisibility_of_element_located` I would suggest you to get a bit granular with the `xpath`

   ```
   WebDriverWait(wd, 10).until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//img[@any_of_the_img_attribute='img_attribute_value']")))
   ```
4. If the amending the above mentioned points doesn't resolves your issue, as a last resort induce some hardcore wait for the Web Page to render after each scroll so next `scroll` can happen.
5. Your final code block may look like :

   ```
   while True:
       wd.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
       try:
           WebDriverWait(wd, 10).until(
           EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="films"]/div[2]/img')))
           WebDriverWait(wd, 10).until(
           EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//img[@any_of_the_img_attribute="img_attribute_value"]')))
           time.sleep(5)
       except TimeoutException:
           break
   ```